# Subtract hours from current date time and compare to column value whose data type is datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want all the `MAFN` column values that were added to the table in the last hour(:mm). The column `ReturnDt` stores the time it was added in DateTime format ex.'2005-01-11 08:50:24.767'

I can get the hours for `ReturnDt` and get the current hour(in two separate queries).

```
SELECT  ReturnDt, 
       DATEPART(hour, ReturnDt) As 
FROM [Sidney].[dbo].[LibraryTransactions]
```

And

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) 'Hour Part'
```

But this is not enough for obvious reasons.
Firstly `SELECT GETDATE()...` doesn't work as a subquery.
Secondly, I can't seem to subtract 1 hour from the result of the `SELECT GETDATE()` query.
Thirdly, even if the above two somehow worked, the queries reduce time to hours and it doesn't take into account the date.

I am using SQl Server 2005

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

The table looks like:
[image]

Expected Result: If I ran the query today(18 Mar 2022) at 16:00 hours I should only get these values
[image]

Comment: I wonder if you have considered using the function `DATEADD()` with a unit of minutes or hours as suits?

Comment: @Dale K  `DTEADD( )` works in SQL Server (starting with 2008). I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Wow... well your first step should be upgrading, because your version is completely out of support and has been for quite some time.

Comment: And I don't think you are correct, I have seen loads of articles referencing using `dateadd` with 2005 are you sure a missing function is actually your error?

Comment: And is `ReturnDt` stored as a `datetime` or `varchar`?

Comment: `WHERE ReturnDt >= dateadd(hour, -1, getdate());` would appear to be what you want.

Comment: Also `GETDATE() 'Today'` should be `GETDATE() AS [Today]` - single quotes shouldn't be used for column aliases both because they look like string literals _and_ they are deprecated in some forms (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) for more info).

Comment: I'll echo what Dale said, I'm not sure why you think `DATEADD()` was introduced in SQL Server 2008. [Here's a reference from the SQL Server 2005 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms186819(v=sql.90)) and that's not even when it was introduced. You can also spot it on page 2,267 of [the 2000 version of Books Online](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/SQL2000_release.pdf) (and the 6.5 or 7.0 docs if you can find those). Also, you could just try it. Or upgrade and not worry about ancient history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about DateDiff()

```
where
   DateDiff( hour, ReturnDT, getdate() ) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. No, this doesn't work. There isn't any difference in the output but at least it doesn't give an error

Comment: it works if I flip the equality sign.
`where DateDiff( hour, ReturnDT, getdate() ) < 1` Thanks again!!

Comment: Why not flip it around so that an index on `ReturnDT` (now or in the future) has some hope to be used? `WHERE ReturnDT >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, cant use DateAdd() because they are running SQL2005 and it is not available, but yes swap equality test

Comment: @DRapp DATEADD() was certainly available in 2005.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, apparently not according to the post user as they indicated not available.  But who am I to say what they have :)

Comment: @DRapp the OP is wrong that `DATEADD()` was added in SQL Server 2008; here's a [documentation page from SQL Server 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms186819(v=sql.90)) that lists its functionality. So I think the OP may be getting some other unrelated error.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, not my issue, nor should this continue of us bickering a point.  They had one thing, they have a resolution, regardless of context. DONE.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick...

Put this in your where caluse:
(column > getdate() - (1.0/24) AND column < getdate() - (2.0/24))

Example: (table 'sometable' contains a datetime column named 'datecolumn')

select * from sometable
where (datecolumn > getdate() - (1.0/24) AND datecolumn < getdate() - (2.0/24))

...will give you records in sometable who are between 1 and 2 hrs old relative "now".